# How can i give colors to google charts

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization, pie-chart

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Invites', 'Count'],
    ['No',  parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['no'])],
    ['Maybe', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['noresponse'])],
    ['Yes',      parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['yes'])]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Job ID '+response['jobData']['id_job']+' Invitation Status'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

This is google chart code in here i want to give specific colors like

No is in red color

Maybe in Yellow

Yes in Green color how can i do that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make options like this:

```
var options = {
colors: ['red','yellow', 'green'],
title: 'Job ID '+response['jobData']['id_job']+' Invitation Status'
};
```